# How to resolve java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException for reading .sys files

Tags: java, security, permissions, file-permissions

First time posting but here it goes. I am attempting to to make a program that reads all files in a drive and hash those files in order to spot potential differences in a "corrupt drive". The program functions fine for all purposes except when encountering files with special permission needs. I have spent days trying to resolve this and have read many stack posts but none that i have found have covered my specific issue. I have tried granting permission through set read and write but does nothing.

I think i found a promising library through java.security.allpermissions but finding examples of how to set it up simply / clearly for a method call has been unfruitful.

The following is the method giving me a hard time.

```
private static String hash(File f, String name) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {

        if(f.isDirectory() == true) {
            
            return "";
        }
            InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()));
            output = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(is);
            
            output = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(name + output);

        return output;  
    }
```

sample output + stack trace:

```
F:\
F:\$Recycle.Bin
F:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18
F:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18\desktop.ini
F:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-3562049501-1359381880-3951677873-1001
F:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-3562049501-1359381880-3951677873-1001\desktop.ini
F:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-4029137503-3596887599-1249178651-1001
F:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-4029137503-3596887599-1249178651-1001\desktop.ini
F:\Documents and Settings
Issue exploring folder: 
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: F:\hiberfil.sys
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at Core.Main.hash(Main.java:47)
    at Core.Main.construct(Main.java:91)
    at Core.Main.run_construct(Main.java:129)
    at Core.Display$SwingAction.actionPerformed(Display.java:297)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: "Run As Adminstrator" may help but will also fail with AccessDeniedException on some paths. You might be better off keeping a set of inclusion / exclusion pathname sets so you don't attempt to scanning paths your account has no access to, or, to skip files like hiberfil.sys that might be pointless to scan.

Comment: Skipping files i don't have access to would defeat purpose of the program, i should add that the idea of "corrupted" drive is by means of another individual perhaps maliciously. So every file needs to be checked.

Comment: Update, so i found out what i need to do, but cannot figure out how to implement it. I need to be able to update the Access Control List for a file. I have found out how to change existing principals in a file via code but cannot figure out how to add a new principal to the ACL list.

Comment: in addition i am finding that the hard drive has references to files on my pc, ie for some reason the documents and settings and users contains references and shortcuts to my pc's files. how do i stop this from happening?